# Improving memory usage during serialization (Data.Binary)

Tags: haskell, memory, serialization, memory-leaks

I'm still kinda new to Haskell and learning new things every day. My problem is a too high memory usage during seralization using the Data.Binary library. Maybe I'm just using the library the wrong way, but I can't figure it out.

The actual idea is, that I read binary data from disk, add new data und write everything back to disk. Here's the code:

```
module Main
  where

import Data.Binary
import System.Environment
import Data.List (foldl')

data DualNo = DualNo Int Int deriving (Show)

instance Data.Binary.Binary DualNo where
  put (DualNo a b) = do
    put a
    put b
  get = do
    a <- get
    b <- get
    return (DualNo a b)

-- read DualNo from HDD
readData :: FilePath -> IO [DualNo]
readData filename = do
  no <- decodeFile filename :: IO [DualNo]
  return no

-- write DualNo to HDD
writeData  :: [DualNo] -> String -> IO ()
writeData no filename = encodeFile filename (no :: [DualNo])

writeEmptyDataToDisk :: String -> IO ()
writeEmptyDataToDisk filename = writeData [] filename

-- feed a the list with a new dataset
feedWithInputData :: [DualNo] -> [(Int, Int)] -> [DualNo]
feedWithInputData existData newData = foldl' func existData newData
  where
    func dataset (a,b) = DualNo a b : dataset

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [newInputData, toPutIntoExistingData] <- System.Environment.getArgs
  if toPutIntoExistingData == "empty"
    then writeEmptyDataToDisk "myData.dat"
    else return ()
  loadedData <- readData "myData.dat"
  newData <- return (case newInputData of
                        "dataset1" -> feedWithInputData loadedData dataset1
                        "dataset2" -> feedWithInputData loadedData dataset2
                        otherwise  -> feedWithInputData loadedData dataset3)
  writeData newData "myData.dat"

dataset1 = zip [1..100000]    [2,4..200000]
dataset2 = zip [5,10..500000] [3,6..300000]
dataset3 = zip [4,8..400000]  [6,12..600000]
```

I'm pretty sure, there's a lot to improve in this code. But my biggest problem is the memory usage with big datasets.

I profiled my programm with GHC.

```
$ ghc -O2 --make -prof -fprof-auto -auto-all -caf-all -rtsopts -fforce-recomp Main.hs
$ ./Main dataset1 empty +RTS -p -sstderr
     165,085,864 bytes allocated in the heap
      70,643,992 bytes copied during GC
      12,298,128 bytes maximum residency (7 sample(s))
         424,696 bytes maximum slop
              35 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       306 colls,     0 par    0.035s   0.035s     0.0001s    0.0015s
  Gen  1         7 colls,     0 par    0.053s   0.053s     0.0076s    0.0180s

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.059s  (  0.062s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.088s  (  0.088s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.003s  (  0.003s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.154s  (  0.154s elapsed)

  %GC     time      57.0%  (57.3% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,781,155,968 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  42.3% of total user, 42.5% of total elapsed
```

Looking at the prof-file:

```
    Tue Apr 12 18:11 2016 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       Main +RTS -p -sstderr -RTS dataset1 empty

    total time  =        0.06 secs   (60 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 102,613,008 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE            MODULE    %time %alloc

put                    Main       48.3   53.0
writeData              Main       30.0   18.8
dataset1               Main       13.3   23.4
feedWithInputData      Main        6.7    0.0
feedWithInputData.func Main        1.7    4.7


                                                                    individual     inherited
COST CENTRE               MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                      MAIN                     68           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                     Main                    137           0    0.0    0.0    86.7   76.6
  feedWithInputData       Main                    150           1    6.7    0.0     8.3    4.7
   feedWithInputData.func Main                    154      100000    1.7    4.7     1.7    4.7
  writeData               Main                    148           1   30.0   18.8    78.3   71.8
   put                    Main                    155      100000   48.3   53.0    48.3   53.0
  readData                Main                    147           0    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
  writeEmptyDataToDisk    Main                    142           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.1
   writeData              Main                    143           0    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF:main1                Main                    133           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    136           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main2                Main                    132           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    139           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   writeEmptyDataToDisk   Main                    140           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    writeData             Main                    141           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main7                Main                    131           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    145           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   readData               Main                    146           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:dataset1             Main                    123           0    0.0    0.0     5.0    7.8
  dataset1                Main                    151           1    5.0    7.8     5.0    7.8
 CAF:dataset4             Main                    122           0    0.0    0.0     5.0    7.8
  dataset1                Main                    153           0    5.0    7.8     5.0    7.8
 CAF:dataset5             Main                    121           0    0.0    0.0     3.3    7.8
  dataset1                Main                    152           0    3.3    7.8     3.3    7.8
 CAF:main4                Main                    116           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    138           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main6                Main                    115           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    149           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main3                Main                    113           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    144           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.Conc.Signal         107           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Encoding         103           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv   101           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Handle.FD         94           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.FD                86           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

Now I add further data:

```
$ ./Main dataset2 myData.dat +RTS -p -sstderr
     343,601,008 bytes allocated in the heap
     175,650,728 bytes copied during GC
      34,113,936 bytes maximum residency (8 sample(s))
         971,896 bytes maximum slop
              78 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       640 colls,     0 par    0.082s   0.083s     0.0001s    0.0017s
  Gen  1         8 colls,     0 par    0.140s   0.141s     0.0176s    0.0484s

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.138s  (  0.139s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.221s  (  0.224s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.006s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.370s  (  0.370s elapsed)

  %GC     time      59.8%  (60.5% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,485,518,518 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  39.9% of total user, 39.8% of total elapsed
```

Looking at the new prof-file:

```
    Tue Apr 12 18:15 2016 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       Main +RTS -p -sstderr -RTS dataset2 myData.dat

    total time  =        0.14 secs   (139 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 213,866,232 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE            MODULE    %time %alloc

put                    Main       41.0   50.9
writeData              Main       25.9   18.0
get                    Main       25.2   16.8
dataset2               Main        4.3   11.2
readData               Main        1.4    0.8
feedWithInputData.func Main        1.4    2.2


                                                                    individual     inherited
COST CENTRE               MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                      MAIN                     68           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                     Main                    137           0    0.0    0.0    95.7   88.8
  feedWithInputData       Main                    148           1    0.7    0.0     2.2    2.2
   feedWithInputData.func Main                    152      100000    1.4    2.2     1.4    2.2
  writeData               Main                    145           1   25.9   18.0    66.9   68.9
   put                    Main                    153      200000   41.0   50.9    41.0   50.9
  readData                Main                    141           0    1.4    0.8    26.6   17.6
   get                    Main                    144           0   25.2   16.8    25.2   16.8
 CAF:main1                Main                    133           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    136           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main7                Main                    131           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    139           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   readData               Main                    140           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:dataset2             Main                    126           0    0.0    0.0     0.7    3.7
  dataset2                Main                    149           1    0.7    3.7     0.7    3.7
 CAF:dataset6             Main                    125           0    0.0    0.0     2.2    3.7
  dataset2                Main                    151           0    2.2    3.7     2.2    3.7
 CAF:dataset7             Main                    124           0    0.0    0.0     1.4    3.7
  dataset2                Main                    150           0    1.4    3.7     1.4    3.7
 CAF:$fBinaryDualNo1      Main                    120           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  get                     Main                    143           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main4                Main                    116           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    138           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main6                Main                    115           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    146           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main5                Main                    114           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    147           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main3                Main                    113           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                    Main                    142           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.Conc.Signal         107           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Encoding         103           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv   101           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.Handle.FD         94           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                      GHC.IO.FD                86           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

The more often I add new data, the higher the memory usage becomes. I mean, it's clear, that I need more memory for a bigger dataset. But isn't there a better solution for this problem (like gradually writing data back to disk).

**Edit:**
Actually the most important thing, that bothers me, is the following observation:

1. I run the program for the first time and add new data to an existing (empty) file on my disk.
   The size of the saved file on my disk is: 1.53 MByte.
   But (looking at the first prof-file) the program allocated more than 102 MByte. More than 50% was allocated by the put function from the Data.Binary package.
2. I run the program a second time and add new data to an existing (not empty) file on my disk.
   The size of the saved file on my disk is 3.05 MByte.
   But (looking at the second prof-file) the program allocated more than 213 MByte. More than 66% was allocated by the put and get function together.

=> Conclusion: In the first example I needed 102/1.53 = 66 times more memory running the program than space for the binary file on my disk.
In the second example I needed 213/3.05 = 69 times more memory running the programm than space for the binary file on my disk.

**Question:**
Is the Data.Binary package for serialization so efficient (and awesome), that it can decrease the needed memory to such an extent.
Analogous question:
Do I really need so much more memory for loading the data in my program than space for the the same data in a binary-file on disk?

Comment: you could take a look at streams if you don't need the entire file in memory at once. This might help: http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/eval-order_themes-delay-stream-section.html

Comment: bigger dataset => more memory? Not if you are streaming the data, and I think binary uses lazy bytestring exactly because of that. Check the laziness in your code (when are you forcing/sharing values).

Comment: why does `feedWithInputData` reverse your input list?  That will not stream.

Comment: Thanks fot the streaming hint, but I think streaming is not an option. The code here is actually a simplified example for the project I'm working on. Here I'm using a simple datastructure like:
data DualNo = DualNo Int Int.

Comment: But in my actual program I have a tree-like datastructure:
data Tree = Tree Int [Tree].
So, I don't need the entire file in memory at once, but I need some branches of my tree-like datastructure in memory. So I think, streaming is not an option, because I won't add new data to the end of the file. I'm going to process my tree-like datastructure (add new nodes or edit existing nodes).
But I have edited my post and added a further question.

Comment: 102 MB is the memory the program allocated, not the memory it occupied (heap peak). Mainly during GC some data may have to be copied and moved. The heap peak of your program (`dataset1 empty`) is around 10MB by heap graph. For how to produce a heap graph of your program please [read this](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html).